# Convert int to  little-endian formated bytes in C++ for blobId in Azure

Tags: c#, c++, qt, qbytearray

Working with a base64 encoding for Azure (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd135726.aspx) and I dont seem to work out how to get the required string back. I'm able to do this in C# where I do the following.

```
int blockId = 5000;
var blockIdBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(blockId);
Console.WriteLine(blockIdBytes);
string blockIdBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(blockIdBytes);
Console.WriteLine(blockIdBase64);
```

Which prints out (in LINQPad):

```
Byte[] (4 items)
| 136         |
| 19          |
| 0           |
| 0           |

iBMAAA==
```

In Qt/C++ I tried a few aporaches, all of them returning the wrong value.

```
const int a = 5000;
QByteArray b;

for(int i = 0; i != sizeof(a); ++i) {
  b.append((char)(a&(0xFF << i) >>i));
}

qDebug() << b.toBase64(); // "iIiIiA==" 
qDebug() << QByteArray::number(a).toBase64(); // "NTAwMA=="
qDebug() << QString::number(a).toUtf8().toBase64(); // "NTAwMA=="
```

How can I get the same result as the C# version?

Comment: Think what your loop does when `i` is 1. It shifts the 0xFF left one bit to get 0x1FE when you wanted 0xFF00.

Comment: is there any eaier way of getting the same result witout the for-loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

```
QByteArray temp;
int blockId = 5000;

for(int i = 0; i != sizeof(blockId); i++) {
  temp.append((char)(blockId >> (i * 8)));
}

qDebug() << temp.toBase64(); // "iBMAAA==" which is correct
```

Comment: Which gives different results from what David Schwartz did.  Which one is correct?

Comment: this one gives the same result as the c# one, atleast the base 64 encoded strings looks the same

Comment: This will convert in little-endian format. My code converts in big-endian format. The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4.aspx) say the original code uses little-endian format.

Comment: then it was little-endian i was after since I needed to replicate the c# version, not just be able to convert to an bytearray. thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 4):

See my comment for the problem with your `for` loop. It's shifting by one bit more each pass, but actually it should be 8 bits. Personally, I prefer this to a loop:

```
    b.append(static_cast<char>(a >> 24)); 
    b.append(static_cast<char>((a >> 16) & 0xff)); 
    b.append(static_cast<char>((a >> 8) & 0xff)); 
    b.append(static_cast<char>(a & 0xff));
```

The code above is for network standard byte order (big endian). Flip the order of the four operations from last to first for little endian byte order.

Comment: Is there any reason why you didn't do `& 0xFF` for the first `append`?  (I would do it on all of them, although on a machine with 8 bit bytes, it shouldn't make a difference.)

Comment: @JamesKanze It's not needed on the first, but it's harmless. I would expect the code generated to be exactly the same.

Comment: It's not needed on any of them, if you're on a machine with 8 bit bytes.  Since `a` has a signed type, it's needed on all of them if the machine has another size of bytes.  (Also, of course: the conversion of a value in the range `[128...255]` is implementation defined if plain `char` is signed 8 bits.  In practice, I've never seen an implementation where it wouldn't work.)

Comment: Is an integer conversion that overflows defined by C++? My recollection is that the results are undefined, but I get this wrong as often as right.

Comment: your byteArray after calling toBase64() gives me "AAATiA==" which is not correct

Comment: See the last two sentences of my answer. Without more context, there no way to know which is wrong. My code uses standard byte ordering. C# apparently produces little-endian. (You should triple-check which you are supposed to be using!)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz §4.7/3: "If the destination type is signed, the value is
unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and
bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.  The C
standard clarifies further, and states that the "implementation-defined
value" can result in a signal being raised.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Whether the conversion is implicit or explicit doesn't change anything.  If you have a value of 140, say, and you convert it to a type with a range of -128...127, the behavior is "implementation-defined", and may signal.  All I can say is in the implementations I know of where `char` is not an 8 bit 2's complement, and the conversion just grabs the relevant bits, plain `char` is unsigned, so the conversion becomes well defined.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the `& 0xff` is needed on all but the first. Otherwise, the result is implementation-defined. The whole point of this code (rather than casting integer to character) is to avoid implementation-defined behavior.

Answer (score -1):

I think this would be clearer, though may be claimed to be ill styled...

```
int i = 0x01020304;
char (&bytes)[4] = (char (&)[4])i;
```

and you can access each byte directly with bytes[0], bytes[1], ... and do what ever you want to do with them.

Comment: I mean you can do "b.append(bytes[0])" things afterward. 0 to 3 if it is little-endian, 3 to 0 if it is big-endian. It's less error prone than the shift things and you can focus on the byte-order.

Comment: It's not portable; you have to adjust it for byte order, it supposes `int` is 32 bits, and it fails completely on the few machines which don't use 2's complement or have padding bits in their `int`.  The shifting says exactly what is going on: the 8 bits in byte `n` are the bits `i...j` in the final int.

Comment: this one did not work at all. produced the base64 "BAMCAbDzMAEB"

Comment: He's obviously messing up with each byte. And now it seems he doesn't actually understand what he's doing at all... How could 4 byte data be encoded to 66 bits...

Comment: He probably pushed the pointer, which interpreted it as a C-style, nul-terminated string, which it's not.